# Building typescript with Node vs. Visual Studio and an outDir

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript

I have a typescript project that I can build with Visual Studio, and I can also build with node. But they both seem to behave slightly differently. My project looks like this (simplified):

```
.
+-- app
|   +-- app.component.ts
|   +-- app.module.ts
|   +-- main.ts
+-- dist
+-- system.config.js
+-- tsconfig.json
+-- packages.json
```

Now when I build, I want to output all the files into the `dist` folder. Therefore my tsconfig.json is set up with an `outDir` as follows:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "dist"

  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "packages/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

Now when I build with node, using `npm run tsc` the dist folder looks like this:

```
+-- dist
|   +-- app
|   |   +-- main.js
|   |   +-- app.module.js
|   |   +-- app.component.js
```

And when building with visual studio:

```
+-- dist
|   +-- main.js
|   +-- app.module.js
|   +-- app.component.js
```

As you can see, the Visual Studio build doesn't place all the files inside the app folder. But the node build does.

Why is this not the same for both, given they are using the same configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my application was utilizing Nuget packages, that also contained typescript files.

- Upon build, Visual Studio would add a packages folder to the root of the project. One of these packages contained *.ts Typescript files.
- Visual Studio, would then adjust the folder structure of the output to incorporate these files. Whereas the `npm run tsc` would not.

The solution is to either:

- Delete the packages folder and build with visual studio; or
- Use a nuget.config file to move the packages folder to another location, either inside the app folder, or up a level outside the scope of the project.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this not the same for both, given they are using the same configuration?

Your assumption is wrong. VS is not using this tsconfig.json.

## Quick Fix

Create a new TypeScript project in visual studio and copy the files over.

## Hard Fix

Figure out what Visual studio is using by editing the project file.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio uses the [MSBuild TypeScript](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/2.4.1) tasks. It is likely not using the tsconfig file, or there is some conflict. Open up your csproj file and take a look at the TypeScript specific nodes. In Visual Studio, you can control most of the values of these nodes by right-clicking on the project, viewing properties, and selecting the TypeScript tab.

Visual Studio is said to [have support for tsconfig files](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html) from 2015 onward (with TypeScript 1.8), but depending on your version of Visual Studio, [that's](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4161) [debatable](http://movingfulcrum.com/visual-studios-bullshit-support-of-typescripts-tsconfig/). It seems there are many that are still having issues.

One way to check would be to run `msbuild` [from the command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx), pointing to your csproj file, and check the output. It should contain the `tsc` output, which should show you if `msbuild` is using the tsconfig file by whether or not the call to `tsc` is using the `-p` or `--project` switch. If it is, then it is attempting to use your tsconfig.

At this point, you are compiling two different ways (with a third test possible):

- `npm run tsc`
- Visual Studio building
- `tsc -p .`

Run it with `tsc -p .` to see if that matches Visual Studio, and maybe the npm task is causing an issue. Either way, you might want to take a look at the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for `rootDir`, which might help you resolve the differences.

Comment: `One or more tsconfig.json files detected. Project properties are disabled.` this seems as though it is at least aware of the tsconfig.json.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more explicit about the potential issues.